# External table in Greenplum - HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, greenplum

I want to create an external table in Greenplum using parquet saved in Hadoop.

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL TABLE test(DT_MONTH date, FLD_002 varchar(250), cnt_oper int, cnr_err int)
LOCATION ('pxf://server:9000/TEST_FOLDER/TEST?PROFILE=Jdbc&SERVER=hivejdbc')
FORMAT 'CUSTOM' (FORMATTER='pxfwritable_import');
```

This is my parquet which I checked using spark:

```
p = 'hdfs://server:9000/TEST_FOLDER/TEST/'
s = spark.read.parquet(p) 
s.show(5)
s.printSchema()
+----------+----------------+--------+-------+
|  DT_MONTH|         FLD_002|cnt_oper|cnr_err|
+----------+----------------+--------+-------+
|2021-04-01|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|       1|      0|
+----------+----------------+--------+-------+
root
 |-- DT_MONTH: date (nullable = true)
 |-- FLD_002: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cnt_oper: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cnr_err: long (nullable = true)
```

In greenplum I have an error

```
SQL Error [08000]: ERROR: PXF server error :
 Error operating EXECUTE_STATEMENT: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
 (seg0 slice1 10.18.205.22:50000 pid=97495)
```

Comment: Can you ask spark to print the schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have used [incorrect parameters.](https://docs.greenplum.org/6-7/pxf/objstore_parquet.html)

The docs say you should have `?PROFILE=hdfs:parquet`

so likely you need somethign like:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL TABLE test(DT_MONTH date, FLD_002 varchar(250), cnt_oper int, cnr_err int)
LOCATION ('pxf://server:9000/TEST_FOLDER/TEST?PROFILE=hdfs:parquet')
FORMAT 'CUSTOM' (FORMATTER='pxfwritable_import');
```

If you need additional paramaters for parquet [they're described here](https://docs.greenplum.org/6-7/pxf/hdfs_parquet.html#customopts).